# Comando top com php não retorna o mesmo valor do terminal

Tags: php, terminal

Bom estou montando um código em php para monitorar o uso da minha CPU. Estou usando o comando top que é nativo no linux. Estou usando um pc com ubuntu server 18.04 para o teste.

Bom o que ocorre é que eu abro o terminal e rodo o php junto, o valor da cpu sempre e maior no terminal, que fica em média em torno dos 20% e o php fica travado em 9.1%.

Vou postar o código que estou montando, queria saber o motivo da diferença e como resolver.

```
    // Executa comando para consulta da CPU
exec('top -d 0 -n 5 -b | grep Cpu', $cpu);
preg_match('/\d+\../', $cpu[0], $cpu_us);

// Monta array com os cores do processador
for($i=1; $i < count($cpu);$i++){
    preg_match('/\d+\../', $cpu[$i], $cores_us);
    $cores[] = $cores_us[0];
}



// Monta o array de resposta
$array = array(
    "cpu" => array(
        "geral" => $cpu_us[0],
        "cores" => $cores
    )
);

var_dump($array);
```

OBS: percebi que sempre que rodo o php os valores dos cores estão mudando, porém o cpu geral não muda muito.